# Handshake failure in CentOS release 5.9 (Final) with OpenSSL 1.0.1e

Tags: curl, openssl, centos, centos5, sni

I need to check a website(https://d1lto7any9tcj3.cloudfront.net/service/index.php) using CURL but my OS is CentOS release 5.9 (Final) OpenSSL is 0.9.8e.

When I used curl -v https://d1lto7any9tcj3.cloudfront.net/service/index.php it said

"error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure"

Reason is SNI problem

after I update the OpenSSL to 1.0.1e but it also give same error

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you duplicate with `echo -e "GET /service/index.php HTTP/1.0\r\n" | openssl s_client -connect d1lto7any9tcj3.cloudfront.net:443 -servername d1lto7any9tcj3.cloudfront.net -ign_eof`? `-servename` uses SNI, so it should test your SNI theory.

Comment: It's not working (11940:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:583)  in CentOS release 5.9 (Final) server but when I tried CentOS release 6.4 (Final) server it's working

Comment: Then its probably not due to missing SNI. You can force `s_client` to use SSLv3 with `-ssl3`.